# Unravel a tree structure stored as nested list

Tags: python, list, recursion, tree

I'm working on a piece of code which simulates possible paths through a series of nodes. The nodes are assigned numbers and the connected nodes are listed in a lookup table. Since the path sometimes splits in two (or many) possibilities (and sometimes only one, i.e., doesn't split) I get a tree-type structure in the form of nested lists. For each level in the list I get a list of possible continuations. For example, a tree of paths pay look like `L = [70, [49, [4]], [94, [120, [144]],[121, [150,[173]]]]]`, i.e., consists of three individual paths `[70,49,4]`, `[70,94,120,144]`, and `[70,94,121,150,173]`.

Is there a nice way to unravel this tree so I can get back the individual paths? The returned format is not very important, as long as I can use it to make a visualization of the nodes changing colors. Note that I have no idea of how long the paths (the depth of the list) may be, so recursion is probably a good idea. Also I don't know how many nodes there are in any one path or how many (allowed) split roads a node will have, except that all those numbers are finite. One way to obtain it manually for the second branch is `L[0], L[2][0], L[2][1][0],L[2][1][1][0]`, if that can be of any help.

Comment: Do you understand how to write recursive algorithms in general? Can you identify a base case? Can you express what needs to happen at each recursive step? Where exactly are you stuck? Does [How to collect results of recursive backtracking?](/q/56917010) answer your question? Or [Recursion using yield](/q/8991840)?

Comment: Well, I generated the nested list using a recursive algorithm. But sometimes you just get stuck in the wrong line of thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could indeed use recursion for this, for instance with a recursive generator:

```
def unravel(lst):
    if len(lst) > 1:
        for child in lst[1:]:
            for path in unravel(child):
                yield [lst[0], *path]
    else:
        yield lst
```

Call like this:

```
lst = [70, [49, [4]], [94, [120, [144]], [121, [150,[173]]]]]

for path in unravel(lst):
    print(path)
```